# About comparing and generating character strings

Tags: swift

I have a point though it is prompt.

It's about comparing dates (string?).

For example, when there are data of 12/1 and 12/5 character strings, I'd like to compare them and obtain data of 12/2, 12/3, 12/4.

In this case, I would appreciate it if you could give me advice on how to generate it.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're asking but you could run a loop that lists all number from 1-5 and then do "12/"+string"element in loop"

Comment: Do you want to generate strings like `12/2, 12/3, 12/4` between `12/1` and `12/5`?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to sort (MM/dd) `String` data?

```
var dateArray = ["12/1", "12/3", "9/2", "10/5", "12/4"]
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd"
dateArray.sort(by: { dateFormatter.date(from: $0)! < dateFormatter.date(from: $1)! })
print(dateArray) //["9/2", "10/5", "12/1", "12/3", "12/4"]
```

**Note:** Force-unwrapping is not recommended if you are not sure the data source is of the format "MM/dd".